# Topography: How to convert raster into vector layers?

Tags: gdal, elevation, polygon-creation, topography, d3

(nb:This project is part of the #Wikipedia #wikimaps project)

**1. Question:**

- **How to create vector topographic maps from raster image ?**
- **How to convert raster topographic image into closed vector polygons for the relevant levels** as seen in [the illustration below](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4687713) ?

Using commands (likely gdal) and a GIS topographic raster image, I want to produce topographic .shp maps with an elegant relief. This .shp should be made of **closed polygons** for each of the n requested level.

[image]

---

**2. Possible direction** would be:

1. Create vector isolines (`gdal_contour -a elev -fl -500 0 500 1000 2000 4000 crop.tif contours.shp`)
2. Create a copy of the whole map area into vector polygon,
3. Cut this polygon with all isolines of level n (i.e. isolines of level 0).
4. Keep those of these polygons with a value (altitude) superior to the isoline value.
5. (merge this polygons into one shp layer of level_n.)
6. Repeat for each level.

I haven't clues how to do that, but it sound promising! (should work) If you can provide the solution to one of the points 2, 3, 4, It will be really appreciated ! and I will be happy to then open a specific question where I will validate your helpful answer.

---

**3. Current workflow: gdal_contours alone is not suitable.** I currently crop my source raster ETOPO using [`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) then get levels with [`gdal_contour`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html). Using the libs `curl`, `unzip`, `gdal`, my current worflow is as follow.

```
# download it:
curl -o ETOPO1.zip 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'
# unzip it:
unzip ETOPO1.zip
# crop it:
gdal_translate -projwin -005.48 051.30 10.00 041.00 ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif crop.tif
# lines for levels:
gdal_contour -a elev -fl -500 -200 0 100 200 500 1000 2000 4000 crop.tif contours.shp
```

Unfortunally, `gdal_contour` generates vertor iso **lines**, which are not suitable. The main trouble is with cropped areas: in the case of a close up on France, the isolines are not closing into a circle as for Islands or continents but open lines, so there are partial parts of the polygons (as the quarter of a circle) whose' relevant fill --a 1/4 pie-- appear as a filled arc (see bug below).

[image: End result in D3js fails due to unclosed isolines generated by <code>gdal_contour</code>]

Comment: An other heuristic could be to: 1. create a copy of the raster area ; 2. delete pixels where elevation < n ; 3. use [polygonize.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) to generate a .shp layer to later import. See : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69062/

Comment: This question was answer on SO main website.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked best to:

1. Reclass the raster

reclass the elevation grid using GRASS r.reclass, see how this works here: [How to reclass a raster with reclassify grid values in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121532/how-to-reclass-a-raster-with-reclassify-grid-values-in-qgis)
This gave me the opportunity to manually define the class breaks.

2. Raster to Polygon

from the menu choose raster>conversion>polygonize (raster to vector)...
make sure to select the reclassified raster as the source raster.
This gave me the polgygon shapefile with the predefined class-breaks.