# Gdal_polygonize: How to filter pixels above a given value (elevation)?

Tags: gdal, cartography, srtm, topography

**Given a topographic GIS raster** of one country:

**Given an elevation threshold n = 50 (meters)**

**How to polygonize pixels when z >= n ?**

[gdal_polygonize.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) is not clear on this point. It states *`This utility creates vector polygons for all connected regions of pixels in the raster sharing a common pixel value`*. So I guess it MUST be like `z = something and only this`. I don't understand where to state the condition.

---

**Current workflow details:**

```
# download:
curl -o ETOPO1.zip 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'
# unzip:
unzip ETOPO1.zip
# crop:
gdal_translate -projwin -005.50 051.30 10.00 041.00 ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif crop.tif
```

Related to: [Topography: How to convert raster into vector layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69049/), [Get a pixel value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25535).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given your `crop.tif` raster layer, you can filter its pixels whose elevation is above the threshold (50 m) using [gdal_calc.py](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py):

```
gdal_calc.py -A crop.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A>=50" --NoDataValue=0
```

The result.tif will be made of 1 where the condition is satisfied, 0 otherwise.
Then, it will be possible to vectorize result.tif using gdal_polygonize.py:

```
gdal_polygonize.py result.tif result.shp
```

Finally, you can filter only the polygon(s) you need creating a new shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr filtered_result.shp result.shp -where "Value=1"
```